# Allowing downlaod after payment

Tags: php

i am confused in how to allows download the file.zip after the payment.If i redirect them to a download page where is file is placed in sever they can download the file again easily or they can pass that link to anyone.

Any suggestions please!

Comment: You must not give url to the physical file. You should give link of your service that will check if user can download file. But there's a lot more than this. In fact, this is quite large topic.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a direct link to the file - use a PHP file that serves the file up as a download, but only if a certain session var is found (created in the confirmation of the payment process)

Answer (score 1):

Just like @SmokeyPHP mentioned, just output the file through PHP instead of linking to it directly.

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

This way you have a full control over who downloads what. Of course depending on the file size, you may wish to split the file into smaller chunks. You don't want to be buffering 40 MB files in your server memory every 5s. With bigger files, you can use something like this:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("file.dat", "r");
while (!feof($file)) {
    echo fgets($file);
}
fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: oo..yes and  i am thinking of some tokens for downloading file...thnxxxxxx

Comment: Tokens are easy. You need to keep track of your user session. Have a variable 'status' or something and see check if the download has already started or if the user is allowed to download. This is basic php.

Answer (score 1):

1. put .zip *file* **outside** the webserver;
2. protect the .zip *URL* with some rule [e.g. being logged in and having purchased the resource];
3. associate the .zip URL with an action that reads the actual binary file and forwards it to user [plenty of examples in here].